# I had multiple triggers A,B which caused transitions between two states S1 and S2, would that pose any problems?

Tags: java, state

I looked into some state diagrams online and don't see any with multiple events which lead to transitions between two states...

For example I have two states A and B and a number of events that can occur X Y and Z that can make A --> B transition.

Ideally I want to do

A------------------------->B

```
     X , Y, Z
```

B---------------------->A

```
     M,N
```

where x y z and m n are triggers. and I have some events where they stay in the same state. 
I am not sure if this is acceptable...

Comment: It would help if you provided some context for your question.

Comment: Sounds fine, but we don't have all the information. Your best bet is either to try it and see, or to tell us more, specifically what problems you think might be caused by this setup.

Comment: not sure of what problems - my question is about correctness- is this correct use of a state machine- having multiple events between just two states ? I have not seen a single example of that.